# What is a solution of $7X\equiv 34 \mod{45}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I just need a solution but it seems like I cannot get. I tried Euclid algorithm and Euler's theorem but no progress.

Comment: See the linked dupes for most all known methods, e.g. by inverse reciprocity or twiddling $\bmod 45\!:\ x\equiv \dfrac{34}7\equiv\dfrac{-11}7\equiv \dfrac{-56}7\equiv -8\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

To find a solution for the congruence equation $7X\equiv 34 \pmod{45}$, we can use modular arithmetic.

First, we need to find the modular multiplicative inverse of 7 modulo 45. The modular inverse of 7 exists if and only if 7 and 45 are coprime (i.e., their greatest common divisor is 1).

Checking their gcd, we have:

$\text{gcd}(7, 45) = 1$

Since the gcd is 1, 7 and 45 are coprime. Thus, the modular inverse of 7 modulo 45 exists.

Now, we can find the modular inverse using the extended Euclidean algorithm or by inspection. In this case, the modular inverse of 7 modulo 45 is 13.

To solve the congruence equation, we multiply both sides by the modular inverse:

$7X \cdot 13 \equiv 34 \cdot 13 \pmod{45}$

$91X \equiv 442 \pmod{45}$

Reducing the coefficients:

$1X \equiv 37 \pmod{45}$

So, the solution to the congruence equation $7X\equiv 34 \pmod{45}$ is $X \equiv 37 \pmod{45}$.

Comment: Thank you so much man. I appreciate it : )

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: It's better to let the OP struggle through it first rather than just give them the answer. Not only that, you can find that same kind of method in the linked duplicates.